# nginx wordpress subdirectory installation

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm trying to separate document root of WordPress installations under subdirectories.

Document root of example.com : /var/www/example.com/

Document root of example.com/xyz : /var/www/example.com-xyz/

after a long research, i was able to resolve all the wordpress sites configured like above.

I used below configuration,

```
root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      }
    }


    location /xyz {

      alias /var/www/example.com-xyz/htdocs/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @xyz;

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            }

    }

    location @xyz {
            rewrite ^/xyz(.*) /xyz/index.php?q=$1;
    }
```

This will worked for long. But Problem is that it I couldn't create a page with name starting with above used subdirectory name. Like, http://example.com/xyzzz
http://example.com/xyz-something

cannot be made since above request will match subdirectory location block :(

So, I tried 
location = /xyz { } 
but I couldnot include

location ~ .php$ { } inside that :(
it will throw error like

```
nginx: [emerg] location "\.php$" cannot be inside the exact location "/xyz"
```

am I doing the configuration in wrong way ? is there any way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `location /xyz/` to avoid problems with other URIs that begin with the same three letters. You can redirect `/xyz` to `/xyz/` with a separate statement. For example:

```
location = /xyz { rewrite ^ /xyz/ last; }

location /xyz/ {
    alias /var/www/example.com-xyz/htdocs/;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: I tried the same and got forbidden suddently and error log had following entry
`[error] 20518#0: *1363 directory index of "/var/www/example.com is forbidden`

Comment: You should add `index index.php;` into your configuration. Near the top of the `server` block perhaps.

Comment: and I tried with index index.php and not luck 


and when tried with `location ~* ^/xyz/*$` 

`location ~* /xyz/` 

and many more, the issue was , .jss, .css , images under /xyz/wp-content/.... and /xyz/wp-includes/ was throwing 404 error .

Answer (score 0):

At last got solution!

changed the following.

```
mainsite root: /var/www/example.com/htdocs/

created following symlinks under mainsite root

site1 -> /var/www/example.com-xyz/htdocs 
site2 -> /var/www/example.com-site2/htdocs
```

and changed the nginx location blocks as following

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      include conf.d/php7.conf;
}

location  /site1/ {

   try_files $uri $uri/ @site1;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-site1.access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-site1.error.log;

    include conf.d/php7.conf;   #this filehave normal phpfpm block like "location ~ \.php$ {  } "

 }

 location @site1 {
   rewrite ^/site1(.*) /site1/index.php?q=$1;
 }
```

NB: `location /something/ { alias /var/www/... }`  created nginx forbidden location issue. (can't use alias )

Here symlinks done all the jobs :) no complex configurations.
Hope this may help someone.